# how to display the last 3 elements from an array?

Tags: php

guys
I have code:

```
@foreach($receivedBills as $bill)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$bill->created}}</td>
      <td>{{"{$bill->date_from->format('d.m.Y')} - {$bill->date_to->format('d.m.Y')}"}}</td>
      <td>{{$bill->cnt}}</td>
      <td>{{$bill->amount}}</td>
      <td>{{$bill->is_paid?'Оплачен':'Не оплачен'}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

It displays all data in a table. I want to display the last three, how can I do this?
I was offered `array_slice($recievedBills, -3)`
but I don't know how to connect it

Comment: Why dont you change your sql query add an order by and limit to it

Comment: `@foreach(array_slice($recievedBills, -3) as $bill)`

Comment: But also what @Baracuda078 says...

Comment: is this the easiest way?

Comment: If you only need the last three then why retrieve them all from the database?  You would only retrieve all if you want to show the last 3 and then show all the rest, better than 2 queries.

Comment: I think what @AbraCadaver says is easyer, but changing your query is in my opinion cleaner and also possible faster for the server you get less data transfer from your database

Comment: ok thx then i need to learn how to make requests